# iphone twitter code explanation

Tags: iphone, twitter

what is this step doing?

following a tutorial to  [integrate twitter into an iphone app](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/) , this steps is done in the target>

> If we right click on this and select Get Info we will see the info about our target. From here we click the build tab and search for the field “Header Search Paths”. You need to add the following into the Header Search Paths:

```
   $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
```

the build works fine, but I want to know what is that accomplishing, linking a library? why not from the normal way of adding libraries?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking the library is a separate task. This is so the compiler knows where to look when you `#import <libxml/...>`.